# can a angularJS event update the value of database?

Tags: javascript, database, angularjs

When button is clicked, a function has been called which change the value of a row which is coming from database? I used AngularJS as JavaScript library and Couchbase as a database.

Comment: Database is server-side concept and JavaScript is client side concept, So both are different.

Comment: the front end javascript will access the app server, which in turn will make changes to the db... no meaning of ur question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not modify Databases directly through client-side Javascript. For this, you will need to use a middleware such as Node Express and Mongoose which will help you communicate between client and DB server.